# WordPress site indexation in search engines

Tags: wordpress, search, content-management-system, indexing, transfer

Are there any facts that Wordpress CMS sites have poor indexation in search engines, and especially when reindexing (updating) site? Is there any logic for that?

Also, if Wordpress site has a page, that can be reached only via many clicks (pagination), does it cause that this page can be not indexed?

I had Wordpress installed on my site - only about 1% of pages were indexed. It had big pagination menu, so the most remote pages were far from the site enter point.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is great for SEO ( search engine optimization ), but it depends on how you configure it and also the theme matters a lot.

There must be other reason your pages weren't indexed.

Comment: Thanks. I think that the pages are too far from the enter point (long pagination). The theme is premium - Prestige. Configuration is normal (no strange things).